# Why does my Android 4.3 Nexus 10 reset during acceptance testing?

Tags: android, testing, crash

I'm running acceptance tests on a Nexus 10 running Android 4.3, but some tests are causing the tablet to reset: it displays the boot animation!

It's failing during a 'swipe' caused by Robotium.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your Settings, under Developer Options, that 'Pointer location' is not on.

This relates to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58769